# Error when parsing JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting the following error:

> uncaught exception: Invalid JSON:
>   {"id":1,"channel":"V125954","text":"{"nick":"Du","visit":"1","text":"hello","_ref":"Du","_cur":"Du","_ip":"Du","_browser":"Du","_os":"Du","_td":"12:29"}"}

When trying to parse with the following function:

```
  var parseJSON = function(data) {
    if (!data || !isString(data)) {
      return null;
    }

    // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
    data = trim(data);

    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if (window.JSON && window.JSON.parse) {
      try {
        return window.JSON.parse( data );
      } catch(e) {
        throw "Invalid JSON: " + data;
        console.log(e);
      }
    }

    // Make sure the incoming data is actual JSON
    // Logic borrowed from http://json.org/json2.js
    if (validChars.test(data.replace(validEscape, "@").replace( validTokens, "]").replace( validBraces, "")) ) {
      return (new Function("return " + data))();
    }

    throw "Invalid JSON: " + data;
  };
```

Data is being sent like this through nodejs:

```
        var options = {
          uri: 'http://localhost/pub?id=' + req.params.channel,
          method: 'POST',
          json: {
            "nick": "Du",
            "visit": "1",
            "text": "hej",
            "_ref": "Du",
            "_cur": "Du",
            "_ip": "Du",
            "_browser": "Du",
            "_os": "Du",
            "_td": "12:29",                                                                                                                                                             
          }
        };

        request_helper(options, function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("ok") 
          }
        });
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: The JSON is not valid, look at http://jsonlint.com/ this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid.

use  http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json file.

corrected json

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "channel": "V125954",
    "text": {
        "nick": "Du",
        "visit": "1",
        "text": "hello",
        "_ref": "Du",
        "_cur": "Du",
        "_ip": "Du",
        "_browser": "Du",
        "_os": "Du",
        "_td": "12: 29"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're JSON string is invalid, that's why you get the error. Try with something like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "channel": "V125954",
    "text": {
        "nick": "Du",
        "visit": "1",
        "text": "hello",
        "_ref": "Du",
        "_cur": "Du",
        "_ip": "Du",
        "_browser": "Du",
        "_os": "Du",
        "_td": "12: 29"
    }
}
```

You can validate your JSON strings at http://jsonlint.org/

The right syntax for nested structures in JSON is:

```
{
   "obj": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

**NOT**

```
{
   "obj": "{
        "foo": "bar"
    }"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the data has the problem

```
{"id":1,"channel":"V125954","text":"{"nick":"Du","visit":"1","text":"hello","_ref":"Du","_cur":"Du","_ip":"Du","_browser":"Du","_os":"Du","_td":"12:29"}"}
```

`"text": "{"nick":"Du...` this part has error u need to escape as `\"nick` or this shud be the data

```
{"id":1,"channel":"V125954","text":'{"nick":"Du","visit":"1","text":"hello","_ref":"Du","_cur":"Du","_ip":"Du","_browser":"Du","_os":"Du","_td":"12:29"}'};
```

Comment: The second example is not valid JSON either. Strings are always denoted by double quotes.

Comment: thanks for marking that but i already specified in the statement about that to escape the quotes.